# SMPP EnquireLink response

Tags: c#, smpp, inetlab.smpp

I'm writing C# code for a SMPP client that connects and binds to a SMPP server. And I'm also using the [InetLab SMPP library](http://inetlab.com/Products/Inetlab.SMPP.aspx).

It opens a connection fine and binds successfully, but it soon disconnects a few seconds later. This is because I'm receiving an EquireLink from the server, but I'm not responding to it to tell the server I'm still alive.

So the question is, "how do I respond to an EnquireLink to tell the server I'm still alive?"

Can someone please show me an example on how to respond to an EquireLink?

Comment: Can't really look into this as I don't have access to an SMSC right now. This library should send the EnquireLink itself, but you may try to periodically send an EnquireLink request yourself by calling `SmppClient.EnquireLink()` and see if that keeps the connection alive.

Comment: I sent an email to InetLab and they confirmed their library has been coded to reply to the EnquireLink automatically. So, there must be something else that's not setup correctly or something. It's a strange one.

Comment: Then maybe check your firewall? Make sure you have port 17600, or whichever port you use to connect to the SMS platform, allowing bidirectional traffic. You can also use something like WireShark to see if anything is being sent back once you receive an EnquireLink request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EnquireLinkInterval which specifies a period of time when SMPP session will be checked with EnquireLink command.